# Multiple image upload & resize freezes chrome or even crashes it

Tags: javascript, image, upload, resize

I have a Javascript that allows to resize multiple images and uploads them. So far it works until you choose more than about 5 files. From about 5 to 25 selected files Chrome browser (or others) just gets really slow, if you choose even more the browser crashes.

It seems to take a lot of memory.

Do you have any suggestions what could avoid the freezing of the browser/computer or the crash?

Thank you very much for your help!

```
// Once files have been selected
document.querySelector('form input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function(event){
$( "#load" ).html( "<img src=\"http://www.maxk.at/image_uploader/ajax-loader.gif\"> Upload l&auml;uft" );
    // Read files
    var files = event.target.files;

    // Iterate through files
    var j=1;
    var k=files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        // Ensure it's an image
        if (files[i].type.match(/image.*/)) {

            // Load image
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

                    // Add elemnt to page
                    var imageElement = document.createElement('div');
                    imageElement.classList.add('uploading');
                    imageElement.innerHTML = '<span class="progress"><span></span></span>';
                    var progressElement = imageElement.querySelector('span.progress span');
                    progressElement.style.width = 0;
                    document.querySelector('form div.photos').appendChild(imageElement);

                    // Resize image
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                        max_size = 1200,
                        width = image.width,
                        height = image.height;
                    if (width > height) {
                        if (width > max_size) {
                            height *= max_size / width;
                            width = max_size;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (height > max_size) {
                            width *= max_size / height;
                            height = max_size;
                        }
                    }
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                    // Upload image
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    if (xhr.upload) {

                        // Update progress
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                            var percent = parseInt(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                            progressElement.style.width = percent+'%';
                        }, false);

                        // File uploaded / failed
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                    imageElement.classList.remove('uploading');
                                    imageElement.classList.add('uploaded');
                                    imageElement.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+xhr.responseText+')';
                                    console.log('Image uploaded: '+j+k+'Abstand'+xhr.responseText);
                                    j++;
                                    if (j==k){$("#load").html("Upload beendet");}
                                    if (k==1){$("#load").html("Upload beendet");}
                                } else {
                                    imageElement.parentNode.removeChild(imageElement);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Start upload
                        xhr.open('post', 'process.php', true);
                        xhr.send(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
                        
                                            }

                }

                image.src = readerEvent.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }

    }
        // Clear files
    event.target.value = '';
    });
```

Comment: it's the FileReader and dataURL use that kills the performance. use window.URL.createObjectURL(file) to get a url instead of the FileReader() part to get a dataURL

Comment: thank you for your hint. Sorry for asking, but my JS knowledge is stil small: what would that look like for the script as above?

Comment: I would be very thankful for your help!